# How to append a custom object to JSONB column type in postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-update

I need to update a jsonb column which contains data `{"X":true}`.
I need to append a complex object of the type `{"obj":{"a":1,"b":2}}` so the final value of row for that column `{"x":true,"obj":{"a":1,"b":2}}` . What will be the query to update this row .

postgres version 12

Update - The following query `update tableName  set columnName = (select '{"obj":{"a":1,"b":2}}'::jsonb || columnName::jsonb) where ...` returns successfully when there is a value present , but when the column is null it still remains null after running the update query . I need to be able to add `{"obj":{"a":1,"b":2}}` even when the column is null .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [concatenation operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html):

```
'{"X":true}'::jsonb || '{"obj":{"a":1,"b":2}}'::jsonb
```

If you want to update an existing column, use `coalesce()` to deal with NULL values:

```
update the_table
  set the_column = coalesce(the_column, '{}')||'{"obj":{"a":1,"b":2}}'
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b39ae5abc9fd02e105712c48ce17262c)

Comment: The following query `update tableName 
set columnName = (select '{"obj":{"a":1,"b":2}}'::jsonb || columnName::jsonb) where ...` returns successfully when there is a value present , but when the  column is null it still remains null after running the update query .

Comment: @divyamsingh13: use `coalesce()` - see my edit. The `select` is useless btw.